# How can I improve cross browser compatibility of my CSS only slider menu?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a css only menu, a back background must slide with animation to selected menu item:

[image: menu screenshot]

```css
.wrapper {
  font: 0/0 a;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.radio {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color .5s linear;
  z-index: 2;
}
.radio:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
}
.radio:checked {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.bg {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: left .25s linear;
  z-index: 1;
}
.radio,
.bg {
  width: 100px;
}
.radio:checked + .radio + .radio + .radio + .radio + .bg {
  left: 0;
}
.radio + .radio:checked + .radio + .radio + .radio + .bg {
  left: 110px;
}
.radio + .radio + .radio:checked + .radio + .radio + .bg {
  left: 220px;
}
.radio + .radio + .radio + .radio:checked + .radio + .bg {
  left: 330px;
}
.radio + .radio + .radio + .radio + .radio:checked + .bg {
  left: 440px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="radio" class='radio' name="r" data-text="Save" checked>
  <input type="radio" class='radio' name="r" data-text="Fork">
  <input type="radio" class='radio' name="r" data-text="Info">
  <input type="radio" class='radio' name="r" data-text="Share">
  <input type="radio" class='radio' name="r" data-text="Edit">
  <i class="bg"></i>
</div>
```

I used `radio` controls and its `checked` state in selectors and render the text by pseudo-elements of `radio`. For radio I used `-webkit-appearance: none` and fixed width.

**The main point of this menu - stay css only. And my problems are:**

- How can I make menu more cross browser compatibility? (now works for webkit only)
- I don't want to use fixed width of navigation elements

[Code source](http://codepen.io/frontenddeveloping/pen/VYYmxL) for more experiments.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the appearance css für the other browsers?

```
.thing {
  -webkit-appearance: value;
  -moz-appearance:    value;
  appearance:         value;
}
```

Code from [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/)

Comment: Try with `-moz-appearance` and get the result... It don't work fine for `radio`. `appearance` without prefix - future support...

Comment: Do you need the radiobuttons in the boxes? How about adding `opacity: 0;` to the `.radio`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a neat affect, but I'm afraid a flexible solution (one that allowed an infinite number of these elements with varying widths) would require some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you can't.

- `apperance` is not supported in all major browsers. (You can add `-moz-apperance` to your style to work in FF, but thats only FF.)
- Bigger problem is, according to [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) `:after` pseudo-element should not work with inputs. `:after` is targeting the element's document tree content, what inputs don't have. You had 'luck' with chrome, they are not following specs, but can't expect other browsers ignoring them the same way.